# onTouchEvent cannot @Override

Tags: java, android, service

Hi i want to implement `GestureDetector` using `Service`

However i have this error `The method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) of type GestureService must override or implement a supertype method`

```
public class GestureService extends Service implements OnGestureListener {

private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();       
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;

 }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {

    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onSingleTapUp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
 }
```

Is there any way to fix it rather than removing the `@Override` as i suspect removing it is the cause that make the `GestureDetector` dont work.

Comment: Can you add some code on how GestureDetector class is declared? What does it implement/extend?

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu hi i have added in the whole code..

Comment: Why at the first place are you trying to add gestures to a service. Service isn't meant for that.

Comment: @Deva i wish to detect the touch/finger movement/gesture in real-time(meaning on top of every application)

Answer (score 1):

There is no onTouchEvent in [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) which results in your error (there is nothing to override). What exactly do you want to do with that event? You can use onDown and onSingleTapUp to emulate the event.
You can however listen to onTouch() from a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), but I don't see any code concerning a View from what you posted at least.

Comment: i wish to detect the touch/finger movement/gesture in real-time(meaning on top of every application)

is it possible to do this using GestureOverlayView?

Comment: I don't think Android supports global gestures that you're talking about right now...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    if (gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I hope this will work.